# Watch node.js object variable in WebStorm debugger

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm, javascript-objects

I have a node.js object variable.

```
var json_sample =
    {
        '81': { length: '2', data: [ '11', '22' ] },
        '82': { length: '1', data: [ 'ab' ] },
        '83': { length: '2', data: [ '21', 'ac' ] },
        '84': { length: '3', data: [ 'af', 'de', 'ad' ], }
    };
```

When I do `console.log(json_sample )`, I can see the printed output.

However, when I want to use WebStorm debugger to view the object contents, I cannot see the content values. All I see is some properties of `__proto__` which are not useful for my debugging.

Is this a limitation of WebStorm debugger in not being able to view object contents? Is one limited to using console.log() for debugging objects?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the screenshot: it looks for me like this in the WebStorm 11.0.3 as well as WebStorm 2016.1
Could you provide a full code example?
[image]

Comment: I modified the question and provided a full code example. You can reproduce the problem with your Webstorm. I am amazed that your Webstorm worked well without problems.

Comment: Yes, modified example made the question clearer. This is definitely the bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20466

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Webstorm debugger cannot show the object if the property name is a number.

This will not work on Webstorm.

```
var json_sample =
    {
        '81': { length: '2', data: [ '11', '22' ] },
        '82': { length: '1', data: [ 'ab' ] },
        '83': { length: '2', data: [ '21', 'ac' ] },
        '84': { length: '3', data: [ 'af', 'de', 'ad' ], }
    };
```

To show the object on Webstorm debugger, make this change.

```
var json_sample =
    {
        'aa': { length: '2', data: [ '11', '22' ] },
        'bb': { length: '1', data: [ 'ab' ] },
        'cc': { length: '2', data: [ '21', 'ac' ] },
        'dd': { length: '3', data: [ 'af', 'de', 'ad' ], }
    };
```

Comment: Seems like a bug with Webstorm.